# How to write text inside an oval shape in Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word

I want to write a text inside oval shape and also want that text should also adapt that shape using Microsoft Word (because I only have Microsoft Word).
I am elaborating my question using this image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just added a label above the shape, and changed it's BackColor to the shape color, AutoSize to False,TextAlign to MiddleCenter and resized the label inside of the shape so the Text will fit on the shape.
But make sure you won't add text that has a length more than the shape width, because it will get ugly!

[image: See here]